# resource selection error using Jenkins External Resource Dispatcher and Flow Plugin

Tags: jenkins, resources

I'm trying to use the Jenkins "External Resource Dispatcher" v1.1.0 plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/External+Resource+Dispatcher) in combination with "Build Flow Plugin" v0.10 plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) in Jenkins v1.551

However, the selection of a resource fails with the following error message:
"No phone chosen even though we have selection criteria, aborting build." and the build aborts.

For a normal job the selection works, well. Just for flow projects I get the error.

Does anybody know how this can be solved?

Any help is really appreciated.